# Should I fit a quasibinomial or a binomial + why is the p value highly significant with a quasibinomial but not with a binomial?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

In my binomial GLM I am trying to deduce which term has the most significant effect using the drop1 function.

I initially ran the model as a normal binomial

```
> Full.Model <- glm(Total_ExProp ~ Sibling_Count + Waketime + Bedtime + SleepTime + AwakeTime,
+                   data = PSD, family = binomial(link = logit)
Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
> drop1(Full.Model, test="Chisq")
Single term deletions

Model:
Total_ExProp ~ Sibling_Count + Waketime + Bedtime + SleepTime + 
    AwakeTime
              Df Deviance    AIC     LRT Pr(>Chi)
<none>             38.646 166.16                 
Sibling_Count  1   38.935 164.45 0.28871   0.5910
Waketime       1   40.509 166.02 1.86310   0.1723
Bedtime        1   39.540 165.05 0.89430   0.3443
SleepTime      0   38.646 166.16 0.00000         
AwakeTime      0   38.646 166.16 0.00000         
Warning messages:
1: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
2: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
3: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
4: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
5: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

However, looking on stackoverflow I saw running with quasibinomial 'suppressed' the warning messages about non-integer success. I got a very different output when I ran with quasibinomial.

```
> Full.Model <- glm(Total_ExProp ~ Sibling_Count + Waketime + Bedtime + SleepTime + AwakeTime,
+                   data = PSD, family = quasibinomial(link = logit))
> drop1(Full.Model, test="Chisq")
Single term deletions

Model:
Total_ExProp ~ Sibling_Count + Waketime + Bedtime + SleepTime + 
    AwakeTime
              Df Deviance scaled dev. Pr(>Chi)  
<none>             38.646                       
Sibling_Count  1   38.935      0.9991  0.31752  
Waketime       1   40.509      6.4476  0.01111 *
Bedtime        1   39.540      3.0949  0.07854 .
SleepTime      0   38.646      0.0000           
AwakeTime      0   38.646      0.0000           
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So my question is how do I know which is correct to use - quasi or normal binomial? Is it the dispersion of the data? If so how do you check dispersion with binomial distributed data?
And finally, why would the p values be so drastically different if quasibinomial rather than binomial?

Comment: I've just found that the dispersion parameter of my binomial GLM was 1 (even though residual deviance/degrees of freedom was 38/111) and my quasibinomial GLM had a disperson parameter of 0.2

Comment: you need to run your binomial glm correctly first, if ```Total_ExProp``` is a proportion, you need to provide the weights or matrix. Then run your quasibinomial and check the dispersion. If yes, indeed it is lesser than 1, it is underdispersed and you can use that